# How to store the id and element name in react js

Tags: reactjs, mern

I need to select a particular employee to assign a task and I am able to assign an employee but meantime I need to store the particular employee Id also in the database. The selection of employees while task adding is from the dropdown list.

```
<select
className="form-control mb-2"
name="employeeName"
value={addTask.employeeName}
onChange={changeHandler}
>
<option selected>...select...</option>
{employeeTaskState.getAllEmpAccounts.map((list)=>{
return(              
<option value={list.name}>{list.name}</option>
)})}
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear, could you rephrase it, usually we do an api call on the onChange method changeHandler and save the data to the database!

Comment: value={list.id}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.